# R data package - Auto detect data structure and include under @format

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

Say I'm documenting a data set as part of an R data package:

```
#' Data Set 
#'
#' This is a description of my data
#'
#' @format This data set contains 40 rows and 6 columns.
#'
```

Is there a way to detect a summary of the data structure upon build rather than hard-coding the structure (i.e. "This data set contains...")?

Comment: Just commenting to make this question active. I don't think you can evaluate R code in roxygen2 ala knitr, but I have also learned never to say "not possible" when working with R...